# how to Back up or Copy and Restore or Load Back .Mdf attached database file

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use SQL Server Express LocalDB and I have a `.mdf` database file free floating attached db.

I have a form with a button, when button is pressed a `SaveFileDialog` is opened.

I want to save the `.mdf` the database wherever the user choses, then I have another form with a button to restore, or in this `.mdf` databases copy and overwrite existing.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ((( connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Expert-Pro-SoftDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))) this is the connection string

    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();            

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Expert"].ToString());

    if (con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
    {
       con.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Backup Database @E TO DISK = @disk", con);
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@E", "DatabaseTest.mdf"));(Another question is how can I find out the path of the Mdf. file when installs on another machine?)
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@disk", saveFileDialog1.FileName));
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Datele au fost salvate", "Expert Pro-Soft Facturare", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    con.Close();            
}
```

I heard that this `.mdf` attached free floating cannot be backed up or restored and can just be copied. And then I want to restore it and overwrite the current `.mdf` with the one that has been saved. Thank you all.

Since it's on disk I thought to copy it, but how you do it, and then replace the copied one with the current one. To copy I have a button, and to reload or restore the copied `.mdf` file I have another button

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not entirely clear on what you want. Since the mdf is already *on* disk, I'm not sure I see what advantage you get by backing it up with SQL commands versus just copying it to another location.

Comment: Yes Brian Washaw, I didn't know what is the best choice here, I want to copy but how to do that, and then with another button I want to replace the current with the one that is copied. I just thought is a better choice Backing up with Sql Commands but it seems is good to copy it and then replace, but how you do it

Comment: Ok. You can copy it using `System.IO` and the `File` class. You can update what you're app is pointing to by modifying the `App.config` file during execution, using the `System.Configuration` APIs to modify and save your config file. When you added your DB file to your app, it added connection string information to your `App.config`--you just need to modify it.

Comment: Brian Warshaw, make a post below so I can mark as answer. Thanks for your Interest. I did File.Copy I saved the .mdf, But when I try to take that .mdf and paste overwrite the current use "The process cannot acces the file, is in use", just please show me below About System.COnfiguration to modify on runtime, to update string Information, thanks again you really helped me

Comment: Brian Warshaw, please help me, since I asked you this question from 10 to 10 min. my eyes are on this site, hoping and praying that you answered this question, I tried working on this since then I can't find a way to do it. When I try to copy access denied...the database it's in use. File.Copy()..what can I do to just make a copy of it to later replace or backup this attached db.